# Moly-based assembly lubricant to cutting lubricant

Tags: lubrication

What's the difference between a Moly-based high pressure assembly lubricant and a heavy duty cutting lubricant, can cutting lubricant be used in place of assembly lubricant or visa versa or is the difference to great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A “cutting lubricant” is not primarily desined to lubricate but to remove the heat generated in the cutting process, otherwise the cutting edges overheat, loose the heat treatment and get damaged - often seen on standard drill bits after people have abused them...

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty of machining SS depends depend on grade 100 to 500 so Mo lubricant although perhaps 5x more expensive make the cutting easier with less cost on cutter replacement rate costs.

Comment: Can you explain what the difference between the 2 is, or is the only difference the price... I'm working on a camshaft

Comment: It’s hard to define tradeoffs without specs, like HD battery vs alkaline